# Was ist die Bedeutung von "pilotiert" hier im Kontext ein Buch von "Bitcoin"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Inspiriert durch empirische Beobachtungen und die Analyse von Wirtschaftskrisen entwickelte er die Theorie des sogenannten »Freigelds« oder »rostenden Geldes« – wie er es nannte. Während der Weltwirtschaftskrise Ende der 1920er und Anfang der 1930er-Jahre wurde die Gesell’sche Theorie als Befreiungsschlag  gegen   die finanzielle und soziale Not von beherzten Unternehmern und Bürgermeistern in zwei kleinen Ortschaften in Niederbayern und in Tirol in der Praxis getestet und erfolgreich »**pilotiert**«.

Bedeutet *pilotiert* hier, dass diese Theorie angewendet wird? Soweit ich weiss, wird dieses Verb von *pilot* auf Englisch deriviert.

Comment: Kommt wahrscheinlich vom [Pilotprojekt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pilotprojekt)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es wurde vom OP falsch zitiert. Das mittlerweile korrigierte Zitat ergibt mehr Sinn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pilotieren hat in den letzten Jahren eine Bedeutungserweiterung erhalten. Früher gab es dieses Wort nur im Sinne von [(ein Fahrzeug) steuern](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pilotieren_steuern_lenken) oder (seltener) [Stützen einrammen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pilotieren_einrammen). Im Bereich des Projektmanagements gibt das [Pilotprojekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilotprojekt) oder im TV-Bereich die ähnliche [Pilotfolge/film](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilotfilm). Auch kurz Pilot genannt. Daraus entstand ebenfalls die Verwendung von pilotieren in diesen Bereichen im Sinne von

> Etwas in der Praxis erstmals testen / erproben / durchführen

bzw auch einfach kurz

> Ein Pilotprojekt durchführen

oder anders gesagt:

> Der fachliche Ansatz wird durch die Pilotierung erstmalig "erprobt".

[Quelle](https://www.computerwoche.de/g/so-gelingen-dms-projekte,40284,7)

Answer (score 1):

Einerseits wohl von Pilot im Sinne von "steuern" abgeleitet kenne ich pilotiert aus dem Projektmanagement und der Softwareentwicklung im Sinne von "erproben".

Comment: hier bedeutet womöglich, dass diese Theorie erfolgerich ist und wird ein Pionier aller Wirtschsftssyteme